# Lack of memory with multiple images

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera

In my application I have to manage lot of images taken by the Android Camera.

The problem is that when I have a lot of pictures the phone has a lack of memory and works very slowly.
I want to still be able to manage the same number of images but without the memory issues

Any advice on what I should do to achieve this?

Comment: where you getting lack of memory post your code

Comment: Manage it better? Without code we can't help...

Comment: How can this question get 5 upvotes? Unbelievable!

Comment: Question is asked bad, maybe not for moderation attention, but shoudn't be upvoted in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decode a scaled images.
You can reduce the amount of dynamic heap used by expanding the JPEG into a memory array that's already scaled to match the size of the destination view. 
The following example method demonstrates this technique:

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).